# How can I run a scaffolded Yesod website in a cabal sandbox?

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

Let's say I have a cabal sandbox at folder `root` and I've installed the yesod packages in it. Then, I do:

```
root> yesod init
```

I go through the prompts and end up with a folder `project` inside `root`.

`yesod devel` doesn't appear to support passing sandbox arguments to it, so any packages I install in the sandbox are not visible to the scaffolded Yesod site (and I don't want to install everything in the global space, because that's impossible to manage and replicate).

I've tried [the suggestion here](http://blog.pangyanhan.com/haskell/2013-11-31-using-cabal-sandbox-libraries.html), but that gives me these errors:

```
root> runhaskell -no-user-package-db -package-db=.cabal-sandbox\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.4-packages.conf.d project/app/main.hs

project\app\main.hs:2:8:
  Could not find module `Application'
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Running it inside `root/project`:

```
root/project> runhaskell -no-user-package-db -package-db=../.cabal-sandbox\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.8.4-packages.conf.d app/main.hs

Foundation.hs:6:8:
  Could not find module `Text.Jasmine'
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Settings.hs:8:8:
  Could not find module `ClassyPrelude.Yesod'
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Settings.hs:14:8:
  Could not find module `Database.Persist.Sqlite'
  Perhaps you meant
    Database.Persist.Sql (from persistent-2.1.2)
    Database.Persist.Sql.Util (from persistent-2.1.2)
    Database.Persist.Class (from persistent-2.1.2)
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Settings\StaticFiles.hs:4:8:
  Could not find module `Yesod.Static'
  Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Does anyone know of a flag I can set or something?

Comment: it's been a while but if you just init a sandbox where you scaffolded your site (`cabal sandbox init --sandbox=[path to yesod-sandbox]`) it should work (although it will install additional packages back to it) - alternatively I think it will also work if you just init a new sandbox (`cabal sandbox init` with `cabal install --dependencies-only`) but then you will get all the packages yet again

Comment: I just found that someone even made a script (using stackage): https://gist.github.com/krdlab/712defa9304069af583d :D

Comment: Thanks @CarstenKönig, that works! I'll be limited to a single Yesod instance to test, but I don't think that will be an issue.

Comment: @CarstenKönig since your comment resolved the question, do you mind posting it as an answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue?

Comment: @sclv ok - thanks for the reminder - sometimes it's hard to tell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

#### just init a sandbox where you scaffolded your site

```
cabal sandbox init --sandbox=[path to yesod-sandbox]
```

#### or alternatively just init a new sandbox

```
cabal sandbox init 
cabal install --dependencies-only
```

#### script

there is even a script [written by KrdLab](https://gist.github.com/krdlab/712defa9304069af583d) that automates this using **stackage**:

```
wget http://www.stackage.org/lts/cabal.config
cabal update
cabal sandbox init
cabal install alex happy yesod-bin
export PATH=./.cabal-sandbox/bin:$PATH
yesod init --bare
cabal install -j --enable-tests --max-backjumps=-1 --reorder-goals
yesod devel
```

Comment: It's the `--bare` flag that made Yesod use the local sandbox (at least for me).